# Computing the Fourier transform of the characteristic function of a cone

Tags: distribution-theory, fourier-transform

I've been trying to compute the Fourier transform of the characteristic function of a cone in two dimensions, e.g., $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : |y| > c|x| \}$. My idea was to guess the solution (e.g. with heuristics and formal manipulations) and then prove that it works, but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: You might want to start your guesswork by abandoning all requirements of the Foubini theorem and integrate directly $\int_0^\infty dy \int_{-y}^{y} e^{ixy} dx $. After having found that integral you should prove - rigorously, of course=) - that this is indeed the Fourier transform of your characteristic function.

Comment: Another approach would be to use polar coordinates.